# shortening this snippet of php and jquery, can it be done?

Tags: php, jquery

so I have a URL containing an array. When the page refreshes, I want to check if certain values are still present in the URL and if not, delete any cookies that may have been associated with it.

The code is as follows:

```
<?php if((isset($_GET['categories']) && !in_array(2, $_GET['categories']))) { ?>
    if($.cookie('hf')=='1'){$.removeCookie('hf');}
<?php } if((isset($_GET['categories']) && !in_array(7, $_GET['categories']))) { ?>
    if($.cookie('hb')=='1'){$.removeCookie('hb');}
<?php } if((isset($_GET['categories']) && !in_array(5, $_GET['categories']))) { ?>
    if($.cookie('hp')=='1'){$.removeCookie('hp');}
<?php } if((isset($_GET['categories']) && !in_array(4, $_GET['categories']))) { ?>
    if($.cookie('hw')=='1'){$.removeCookie('hw');}
<?php } ?>
```

This works perfectly, but is it the best way to go about checking the array and clearing any eventual cookies?

Any help or confirmation is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think you might be looking for codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I never knew it existed, thank you PlantTheldea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['categories']))
{
    foreach(array(2 => 'hf', 4 => 'hw', 5 => 'hp', 7 => 'hb') as $key => $value)
    {
        if(!in_array($key, $_GET['categories']))
        {
            echo 'if($.cookie(\''.$value.'\')==\'1\'){$.removeCookie(\''.$value.'\');}';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

That's not shorter, but cleaner.

Comment: this is deleting the cookie even with the value in the URL. I only want the cookie deleted if the value isn't in the URL.

Comment: interesting, I never knew you could echo jquery within php like this. and it works beautifully. thank you very much, look a lot more professional now!

Comment: I you didn't know this, that means that you have not yet understood the difference between server-side and client-side code. I suggest you read **[the first answer here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming)**.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily more readable (but could be readable if you rename function and arguments), but this is shorter and should work.

```
<?php function x($a,$b) {if((isset($_GET['categories']) && !in_array($a, $_GET['categories']))) { echo "if($.cookie('".$b."')=='1'){$.removeCookie('".$b."');";}
x(2,'hf');
x(7,'hb');
x(5,'hp');
x(4,'hw'); ?>
```

Comment: You forgot to prefix variables with `$` and to replace `2` with `$a` ;)

Comment: Thanks, overlooked that.

Comment: this is pulling up coding errors, even the edited version,, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I find this solution simple and also easy to extend in the future:

```
$a = array("hf" => 2, "hb" => 7, "hp" => 5, "hw" => 4);
$b = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'categories', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);
if ($b) {
    $keys = array_keys(array_diff($a, $b));
    foreach ($keys as $val) {
        echo 'if($.cookie("' . $val . '")=="1"){$.removeCookie("' . $val . '");};';
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this isnt working, probably because the first line isn't correctly being defined as an array. but thank you for your time.

Comment: It must be due to your php version, im going to change it to make it more compatible with older versions of PHP

Comment: thanks for your input. The reason I accepted the other answer is simply because I understand the coding a little better.

Comment: No worries. What I'm doing is filtering the values of the array to avoid undesired input (good practice). Then I make a diff between the arrays in order to filter values. I then get the array of keys of that array and loop over it to ouput the text.